# Mockito NullPointerException thrown instead of custom ExitException

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to test the functionality of my `ApplicationRunner` class which currently depends on a simple `CLI` class. Using mockito, i'm attempting to mock the `CLI` and determine the conditions on which a custom `ExitException` is thrown. (when the `CLI`s `help()` method is shown). My issue is that the test is throwing a `NullPointerException` rather than an `ExitException` when it his the `parse` function.

Test code:

```
public class ApplicationRunnerTest {

@Mock
private APUCLI cli;

private ApplicationRunner runner;

@Before
public void prepareDependencies(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    runner = new ApplicationRunner();
}


@Test(expected = ExitException.class)
public void verifyHelpOptionsRun() throws Exception{
    String[] args = new String[]{};

    runner.run(args);

    when(cli.parse(args)).thenReturn(null);

    verify(cli, times(1)).parse(args);
    verify(cli, times(1)).help();
}

}
```

The cli class which is mocked:

```
@Component("Cli")
public class APUCLI implements CLI {


@Override
public ParsedArgs parse(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Parsing CLI");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void help() throws ExitException{
    System.out.println("something");
    throw new ExitException(1);
}
}
```

The APU Runner code.

```
@Component("Runner")
public class ApplicationRunner implements APURunner{

@Inject
@Named("Cli")
private CLI commandLineInterface;

@Override
public void run(String[] args) throws ExitException{
    ParsedArgs parsedArgs = getParsedArgs(args);
    if(parsedArgs == null){
        callHelp();
    }

    System.out.println("Running");

}

private ParsedArgs getParsedArgs(String[] args){
    return commandLineInterface.parse(args);
}

private void callHelp() throws ExitException{
    commandLineInterface.help();
}
}
```

The error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<Systems.biology.laboratory.ExitException> but was<java.lang.NullPointerException>

at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Systems.biology.laboratory.runners.ApplicationRunner.getParsedArgs(ApplicationRunner.java:33)
at Systems.biology.laboratory.runners.ApplicationRunner.run(ApplicationRunner.java:23)
at Systems.biology.laboratory.runners.ApplicationRunnerTest.verifyHelpOptionsRun(ApplicationRunnerTest.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:19)
... 15 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues (at least) :

1) You mock a `APUCLI` instance :

```
@Mock
private APUCLI cli;
```

But you never set it to the `ApplicationRununer`  instance under test. So the `APUCLI` field defined in the `ApplicationRununer` instance is `null`.

You could provide a constructor that allows to set the dependency.

So you could replace :

```
@Inject
@Named("Cli")
private CLI commandLineInterface;
```

by :

```
private CLI commandLineInterface;

@Inject
public ApplicationRunner(CLI commandLineInterface){
     this.commandLineInterface = commandLineInterface;
}
```

You could so create it in this way :

```
@Before
public void prepareDependencies(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    runner = new ApplicationRunner(cli);
}
```

About the `@Named` qualifier, sorry I am not sure about the way to specify it in a autowired constructor with a javax `Inject` annotation.
So I prefer put this point aside.

2) You set the mock behavior after executing the method to test. It is too late.It should be done before if you want that it be considered during the execution of the method to test.

```
@Test(expected = ExitException.class)
public void verifyHelpOptionsRun() throws Exception{
    String[] args = new String[]{};

    // mock record first
    when(cli.parse(args)).thenReturn(null); 

    // execute the method to test
    runner.run(args);        

    // do some checks (if required)
    verify(cli, times(1)).parse(args);
    verify(cli, times(1)).help();
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you! I also had to mock the behaviour of the `cli.help()` call, but the test now passes.